# How do I create a restricted user account in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to create a user account that has limited access to the PC. This is for a friend of mine who sometimes uses my PC. I have setup the policies I want in the group policy editor. How do I create a user account in which the group policies will work? I've tried mmc.exe however whenever I test it(such as disabled access to command prompt), it doesn't work(command prompt still works). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set the user up as a Standard User (regular Windows 10 account setup to limit access).  Then the user cannot install software or alter the registry (which limits any kind of admin activity).   This has worked well in all our clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have setup the policies I want in the group policy editor.

I think you will find there is no need for trying to do this with Group Policies.

Just set the user up as a Standard User (regular Windows 10 account setup to limit access). Then the user cannot install software or alter the registry (which limits any kind of admin activity). This has worked well in all our clients.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standard user account. Any user account you create is standard by default. Standard user has limited permissions, it cannot install software, edit registry/group policy, cannot run administrative software without credentials. You can apply even more restrictions. I would recommend to enable the Guest account for him.